# Is there an advantage to using the warnings module in Python rather than printing a warning, when the warning is just for reference?

Tags: python-3.x, warnings

Here are two examples of warning the user if the variable x is not equal to 'apple':

First the set up:

```
import warnings

x = 'banana'
```

First example, just using print:

```
if x != 'apple':

   print('Warning: X is not apple!')
```

returns:

```
Warning: X is not apple!
```

The second example uses the warnings module:

```
if x != 'apple':

   warnings.warn('X is not apple!',UserWarning)
```

returns:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: UserWarning: X is not apple!
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

If all I want to do is produce output either on the Jupyter Notebook or in the command window where the script is being run, is there any advantage to using the warnings module to do so, or is the print function sufficient?  I want to achieve a user warning in the most pythonic manner i.e. what is best practice here?

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0230/#motivation?

Comment: I have now thanks.  It does not really answer my question.  Instinctively, I feel like a simple print function is the best here, since these motivations are not really necessary for the use case that I present above.  Although, I am not sure, hence the question.

Comment: As an alternative to the normal `print`, this is usually a case where I use `sys.stderr.write()` as as an alternative output. It has the added bonus that in Jupyter notebooks it shows up with a pink background that distinguishes it from typical stdout output. A lot of times, I use that in the notebooks for distinguishing user feedback from the actual output as the script runs. Lately by adding Will McGugan's [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) I can do much more fancy stylizing that shows in both Jupyter and command line versions.

Comment: Here are demos of the styling you get from those two approaches in notebooks: [sys.stderr.write()](https://github.com/fomightez/cl_sq_demo-binder/blob/master/notebooks/Demo%20of%20script%20to%20calculate%20differences%20between%20sequences%20in%20multiFASTA%20file.ipynb) and [rich](https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/pdbepisa-binder/blob/main/notebooks/Working%20with%20PDBePISA%20interfacelists%20in%20Jupyter%20Basics.ipynb). I suspect warning module use for your example is overkill & may cause concern undue for some users. Hopefully these suggestions gave you some additional options.